# Change Gunicorn/Virtualenv/Nginx python version

Tags: python, django, nginx, virtualenv, gunicorn

I'm quite newbiew with server configuration so I've created a droplet from DigitalOcean that has Django on Ubuntu 14.04.

My app was running pretty fine but after a few changes I started facing a few issues related to environment. I'm developing with Python 3.4 and Django 1.7 and my server is running with Python 2.7 and Django 1.7.

Question: how can I make the server run with the proper python version? This may help:

```
# python --version
Python 2.7.6
# python3 --version
Python 3.4.0
```

This is the tutorial I've followed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just code python version agnostic? Django has the six library for this reason and there also is the future module available on PyPi.

Comment: I've downloaded a huge sample that has lots of code that depends on Python3.x. And, even if it wasn't the case, I'd like to move forward since the beggining of my env. :)

Comment: Ok, then I think you're in a bit of a jam. You added virtualenv to the tags, but from the documentation you linked I see no evidence that virtualenv is in play here, otherwise it would be a whole lot easier to change your setup. So you chose a click and work interface cause you lack the knowledge to configure the stack yourself. The drawback is that you then have to work within the confines of this stack. To change it you need to use apt or pip to install Django for python 3.4 reconfigure GUnicorn for the new Django and reinstall any python libraries for your app.

Comment: Yep, I know.. I thought it'd be faster and easier but customization have become a pain in the ... Thanks anyways